# Интересная тема для курсовой

Tags: delphi

Посоветуйте, надоела банальщина и переписывание "велосипедов" (:

Comment: А что Вам самому интересно?

Comment: Главное, смотрите, что Вам самому интересно и интересено ли Вам это вообще.
На 2 курсе делал курсач в Delphi, используя 3D графику: программка кушала файл с координатами дороги и отображала движение автомобиля по этой дороге. Работа очень понравилась. Использовал OpenGL - примеров в инетернете хватает, в том числе и на Delphi.

Comment: Уважаемый @Андрей Куликов,
каков, примерно, должен быть объем курсовой?

Comment: Я когда-то делал сайт-экзешник) при запуске вешался сокет на 80-й порт, обрабатывались запросы, из ресурсов доставались стили-скрипты и т.д. Соответственно, можете добавить туда какой-то функционал специфический, должно получиться интересно.

Comment: @Андрей Куликов: Область интересов назовите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

У вас наверняка есть друзья/родственники, работающие в офисе - спросите какая программа помогла бы в их работе.

Comment: Так и сделал :))

Comment: подсказали что-нибудь?)

Answer (score 0):

Работа с Базой Данных(MySQL к примеру)

Comment: Куда банальнее то?

Comment: Ну поработайте с noSQL БД =)

**warning**, от SQL СУБД потом воротит

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется что-то своё написать, то самый нормальный на, мой взгляд, вариант - это какая нибудь БД. Одна база от другой, содержащей информацию об одной и той же области, может сильно отличаться. При этом актуальность АИС, основанных на БД, пока ещё не падает, а разных прикладных программ уже много.